# How to push to an array from within a function that is nested inside of an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm trying to make a dice rolling application for a friend, where the user can define the number of sides on their die (like 2, 12, 37, etc) as well as the number of these dice that the user wants to roll. I want the results of my rolls to be written to an array, so I can (ultimately) list not only the TOTAL of the rolls, but also list the individual rolls that make up the total. I can't get the array to work within my code, however.

This is pure javascript, with no other libraries or anything. I've tried creating a variable, and letting my "roll" exist within a variable, but it doesn't seem to work.

This is what I'm trying to implement:

```
//call the roll function on the click of a button
//also roll the same die numOfDie times
//add each roll to an array
//ultimately print the array, to see the values of each roll
rollButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var arr = [];
    for(var i = 1; i <= numOfDie.value; i++){
        var result = roll(typeOfDie.value);
        arr.push(result);
    };
    console.log(arr);
});


//roll a die with typeOfDie sides
function roll(i){ 
    var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * i + 1)
    console.log(roll);
    totalRoll.textContent = roll;
};
```

This is my code that I know for sure works, but does not have the array functionality that I want. It simply rolls the die a number of times.

```
//call the roll function on the click of a button
//also roll the same die numOfDie times
rollButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    for(var i = 1; i <= numOfDie.value; i++){
        var result = roll(typeOfDie.value);
    };
});


//roll a die with typeOfDie sides
function roll(i){ 
    var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * i + 1)
    console.log(roll);
    totalRoll.textContent = roll;
};
```

I expect to have an output of an array with each of my rolls (something like arr = [4, 5, 1, 12, 10]) but instead I get an output (in the console) of something like arr = [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `return` to return the value in the roll method. This way the variable `result` gets the correct value instead of undefined. Checkout the following snippet:

```
//roll a die with typeOfDie sides
function roll(i){ 
    var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * i + 1)
    console.log(roll);
    totalRoll.textContent = roll;
    return roll;
};
```

Comment: I see! This is in fact the solution. Could I ask for some clarification though? Why does adding `return roll;` seem to only effect the functionality of my `var result = roll(typeOfDie.value)` variable? Doesn't the `roll` function already "return" its result?

Comment: Great! Functions have the return type `void` by default, this means they return nothing when calling them. This can be useful when logging something to the console or running code where the result isn't relevant. Most often you would want to use the `return` keyword. This keyword can be used to return a value for the caller(`var result = roll()`) in this example. Any value can be returned such as but not limited to: `string`, `array`, `numbers` and `objects`. Using return is preferred over using a global variable because it limits the ways data can be changed. @Surpex